# apache solr max and min in single query

Tags: solr

We are migrating from mysql to apache solr since solr is fast in searching. Thank you. We had a scenario to

> find 1) difference (max-min) 
>        2) with group by date(timeStamp)

Given below is our mysql table :

[image]

And our mysql query is,

```
SELECT Date(eventTimeStamp), MAX(field) - MIN(field) AS Energy FROM PowerTable GROUP BY DATE(eventTimeStamp);
```

will results,

[image]

So we have to calculate difference per day, where date column is in datetime format.

To reflect/migrate above mysql query in apache solr, we are using result grouping as

```
group=true&group.query=eventTimeStamp:[2019-12-11T00:00:00Z TO 2019-12-11T23:59:59Z]&group.query=eventTimeStamp:[2019-12-12T00:00:00Z TO 2019-12-12T23:59:59Z]
```

Using Apache solr statistics option, we are able to calculate max and min for whole result, But we need max and min value per day basis.

[image]

When we try to get max and min value per day basis, we are able to fetch either min or max using following query.

```
&group.sort=event1 desc or &group.sort=event1 asc
```

[image]

Definitely you have to spend some effort/time to understand this question.

**So how to find both min and max in single query (per group; not for whole result).**

Comment: The JSON Facet API allows statistical function across buckets, so adding a field that has just the date and then using that for faceting should work: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/json-facet-api.html (also, be aware that Solr might not be well suited as your primary data store, as changing the schema will require reindexing your data from a secondary source).